# How to properly disable InnoDB full-text stopwords for MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, full-text-search, innodb

I've tried lots of things suggested by various users here on stack overflow but none seems to be working and it's really problematic when user used **`the`** keyword.

For, example I tried with:

1. Creating empty innodb table with value column...

```
innodb_ft_enable_stopword=1
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table=db_name/table_name
```

and this didn't work.

2. Modyfing `my.cnf` on `[mysqld]` part with...

```
innodb_ft_enable_stopword=OFF
```

3. Set `GLOBAL` or `SESSION` with...

```
SET @@SESSION.innodb_ft_enable_stopword = 'OFF';
```

4. Restarting mariadb via `sudo service mysql restart` and deleting / recreating index.

I'm out of options, if someone can, please write here a proper way to disable thing thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since your storage maybe innodb or aria(myisam), you may actually try the following steps:

- Set the variables in my.cnf

```
innodb_ft_enable_stopword=OFF
ft_stopword_file=''
```

- Restart mariadb (maybe `service mysql restart` or restart your docker container)
- Rebuild the index, for tables of innodb, this would be

```
analyze table <YOUR_TABLE>;
```

For tables of aria(myisam), this would  be

```
repair table <YOUR_TABLE>;
```

Comment: To rebuild the index for MariaDB InnoDB, it must be `alter table <YOUR_TABLE> force;` instead. For MyISAM, we can also use `repair table <YOUR_TABLE> quick;`. Other parts of this answer are all OK in my test. So, I have verified this solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the file to an empty file.
2. Restart MariaDB.
3. Rebuild any FT indexes that depend on this change.